# How can I extract similar phrases?

Tags: java, lucene

I am using Wordnet database. It gives me just the meanings or synonyms for 1 or 2 words. If I want similar phrases, how to do that? Please, any one help me on this. Also I am making use of Lucene in my code. If there is any way of doing it with lucene?.

```
    WordNetDatabase database = WordNetDatabase.getFileInstance();
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < list1.size(); i1++) {

            Synset[] synsets = database.getSynsets(list1.get(i1));
            for (int i = 0; i < synsets.length; i++) {
                String[] wordForms = synsets[i].getWordForms();
                for (int j = 0; j < wordForms.length; j++) {
                    out.print(wordForms[j] + "\n");
                }
                out.println(synsets[i].getDefinition() + "\n");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lucene has similarity scoring, https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/Similarity.html

This should allow you to score two strings against each other and then specify and minimum similarity between the strings, thus allowing you to find similar strings.

Comment: most of the time i found of scoring the similarity. but not sure how to show the similar queries. can u give me some link to examples.